# Javafx & running in Vs code

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, javafx

I just installed javafx and used its jar libraries in my reference libraries of my projects. I have trouble running my javafx programs even simple ones. for example :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class JavaFxApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 0 0 5 0; -fx-border-style: dotted;");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 800, Color.RED);

        //TODO your code goes here
        // try to separate logic from GUI

        RecursiveGUI recursiveGUI = new RecursiveGUI();
        // Setting stage properties
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        stage.setTitle("Recursion in JavaFX!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

it's my JavaFxApplication and I also wrote its launch.json like this :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch JavaFxApplication",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "ir.ac.kntu.JavaFxApplication",
            "projectName": "tahw11-recursion-gui-starter",
            "vmArgs": " --module-path D:/javafx-sdk-18.0.1/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
        }
    ]
}
```

and correctly referenced my javafx/lib folder.
I have no idea what the problem is, it looks like sth lacks because when I run this, nothing happens and program looks like it's waiting.
I know this is not an exact problem but I'd appreciate any help to know any case that may cause such a problem and all the possible cases that should be noticed. thank you!
Also it's good to know this happens when I run & Debug, but when I run without debug it gives me can not find symbol error and says that imported libs doesn't exist!

Comment: What is `RecursiveGUI`?  That could be your problem. The very name seems suspicious that it could hang the JavaFX thread if coded incorrectly?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and full text of all errors and the execution command, formatted as code.

Comment: Execution instructions for JavaFX apps in vscode are in the getting started instructions at openjfx.io.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

I suggest you create a JavaFX project. You can refer to the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-gui) for more details.

And make sure you read the [introduction](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) to JavaFX.